# Displaying data doesn't show anything

Tags: angular

I'm trying to show some data from the widget inside another component in the app. I create html widget file and ts file and I want to show it component but all I get is the card with words but not with numbers from public data.
The console doesn't show any problem except error with length property after click "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" but I don't think that's the reason why it doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

widget html file

```
<mdb-card (click)='toggle()'>

    <h4>Revenue</h4>
    <p>Actual {{item?.revenue.actual}} $<br>
      Change {{item?.revenue.change}} %</p>

  </mdb-card>
```

widget ts file

```
export class DsWidgetComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  public swiperconfig: SwiperConfigInterface = {
    observer: true,
    a11y: true,
    direction: 'horizontal',
    speed: 200,
    effect: 'slide',
    coverflowEffect: {
        slideShadows: false,
        depth: 0,
        rotate: 30
    },
    init: true,
    loop: false,
    freeMode: true,
    resistance: true,
    resistanceRatio: 0,
    spaceBetween: 15,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    keyboard: true,
    mousewheel: true,
    nested: true,

};

    @Input() public item;
    public record = 0;
    ngOnChanges() {
    }
    ngOnInit() {

    }



    public toggle(): void {
      this.record = this.record >= this.item.length - 1 ? 0 : this.record + 1;
  }

}
```

the component in which you want to use information from the widget
html file

```
<div class="container-fluid" *ngIf="data?.length > 0">
  <swiper #swiper [config]="swiperconfig">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data;">
          <div class="swiper-slide ">
              <app-ds-widget-component
                      #card
                     [data]="{data:item}"

              >
            </app-ds-widget-component>

          </div>
      </ng-container>

  </swiper>

</div>
```

ts file for it

```
export class DashboardComponent {



    constructor(
      public loginService: LoginService,
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private riotService: RiotService,
      private sg: SimpleGlobal,
      private translate: TranslateService,
      private applicationRef: ApplicationRef,
      private router: Router,
      private dictionaryService: DictionaryService,
      private cookieService: CookieService,
      private functionService: FunctionService,
      public idle: Idle
  ) {
  }

    public data =
        [
            {'revenue': {'actual': '123', 'change': '25 '},},

            {'revenue': {'actual': '23 ', 'change': '23 '},},

            {'revenue': {'actual': '43 ', 'change': '12 '},},

        ];

        public swiperconfig: SwiperConfigInterface = {
          observer: true,
          a11y: true,
          direction: 'horizontal',
          speed: 200,
          effect: 'slide',
          coverflowEffect: {
              slideShadows: false,
              depth: 0,
              rotate: 30
          },
          init: true,
          loop: false,
          freeMode: true,
          resistance: true,
          resistanceRatio: 0,
          spaceBetween: 15,
          slidesPerView: 1,
          keyboard: true,
          mousewheel: true,
          nested: true,
          freeModeSticky : true
      };


    public record = 0;



    ngOnInit() {

    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
    }
    public toggle(): void {
        this.record = this.record >= this.data.length - 1 ? 0 : this.record + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the function `toggle` called?

Comment: in widget <mdb-card (click)='toggle()'>

Comment: `[data]="{data:item}"` should be `[item]="item"`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change your **html** from:

```
 [data]="{data:item}"
```

to:

```
 [item]="item"
```

and your **ts** from:

```
 public toggle(): void {
    this.record = this.record >= this.data.length - 1 ? 0 : this.record + 1;
}
```

to:

```
 public toggle(): void {
    this.record = this.record >= this.item.length - 1 ? 0 : this.record + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused. You doing a ngFor with `let item`:

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data;">
      <div class="swiper-slide ">
          <app-ds-widget-component
                  #card
                 [data]="{data:item}"

          >
        </app-ds-widget-component>

      </div>
  </ng-container>
```

You call the property `data` and give it in your component `ds-widget-component`. But then you use `{data:item}` instead of `item`. In the widget you declare it as `item` again but announced as `data` before. Maybe I am mistaken but...

it should be:

```
[item]="item"
```

Inside widget.ts:

```
@Input() item;
```

Inside widget.html

```
<mdb-card (click)='toggle()'>

    <h4>Revenue</h4>
    <p>Actual {{item.revenue.actual}} $<br>
      Change {{item.revenue.change}} %</p>

  </mdb-card>
```

Comment: When I change [data] to [item] as you suggested, card show all Information.Thank you very much.  About widget file I used {{item.revenue.actual}} earlier but console show me the problem with  TypeError: Cannot read property 'revenue' of undefined" so I add "?" as a solution for this problem I change it again it seems to work without any console errors :) Nice thanks

Comment: So it was just by accident still in the code? Glad if I could help. If you like you can upvote my answer to mark here as useful.

Comment: Yes, it was very useful, again thanks for helping me. I'm afraid I can't upvote your answer because of that   "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." I'm new here so I can't do a lot of stuff :D  But I will remember to do so in future